# Scrappy shell is not returning the whole page

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I have following issue.

When I run this scrappy shell:
`scrapy shell "http://en.50partners.fr/Startups/"`

I expect to retrieve the full page, unfortunately when I run `view(response)` I'm retrieving the page without the startups section itself. Do you have any idea, how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part with the startups is loaded dynamically.

Try to open the initial page in a browser of your choice with JavaScript turned off and you'll get the same result.

Now inspect the HTML of this page to see this:

```
<div class="Folder_page_block startups"
data-children-count="46"
data-children-reload-url="http://en.50partners.fr/fiftyPartners/ajax/folder/67/children/%page%/%limit%/%view%"
data-children-view="line">
```

There's the url from where the data is loaded.
You might want to fiddle a bit with the url, strip everything after "children" and start another Request with this URL.

The resulting response isn't the HTML you might expect. You might want to `import json`, run `json.load(response.text)`, and inspect the resulting list.

Have fun :)